# json post with cURL from a while loop

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to post json data with cURL. The idea is: In case the url is not accessible ( for example failure of internet connection) keep trying to post the json while you succeed. It works but when I put it in while loop it executes only once. What am I doing wrong:

```
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($event);
echo $jsonDataEncoded;
echo "\n";

$send_failure = true;

while ($send_failure) {

$url = "a";// intentionally inaccessible url

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:    application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($jsonDataEncoded))); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));

} else {$send_failure = false;}
return $result;

}
```

Comment: throw (without a try catch) and return will both end the execution of the current function. Given that either one or the other happens on the first iteration of the loop, you'll never get beyond that.

Comment: Did you try closing cURL connection at the end of each loop? curl_close($ch);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must print and check the value in $result using var_dump($result); .
If there is any connection error it returns the error code which you can check manual in IF condition. Hope this might help you.